# Post from HTML page to Google Drive Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-drive-api

I'm trying to collect mails from a web page. Need some help top find out what i'm doing wrong in the script. When i click the submit button it's redirecting me to the form and it's asking me to fill out the form it does'nt take the mail i send i'm from my HTML form.

I hope someone is good enough with JS and google drive to help me.

-All files are shared to public and i already created the form document before trying to run the script.

-this is the script i writed in my HTML file:

---

```
<html>
<head></head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<body>

<form id="email-form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14vkwbJgeJEbXO9R4ce4UssTCI1hAY8M7kP-uUZujIzI/formResponse" method="POST" target="no-target">
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="enter email" name="email">
  <button id="email-submit" type="submit"></button>
</form> 
<iframe src="#" id="no-target" name="no-target"></iframe> 
</body>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$('#email-form').one('submit',function(){
var emailAddress = encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());
var baseURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14vkwbJgeJEbXO9R4ce4UssTCI1hAY8M7kP-uUZujIzI/formResponse?entry.983095800=';
var submitRef = '&submit=submit';
var submitURL = (baseURL + emailAddress + submitRef);
$(this)[0].action=submitURL;
$('#email').addClass('active').val('Thank You!');
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#form-container').hide();
  $('#update-form').animate({'width': '0px'},300,function(){
    $('#get-updates-link').hide();
  });
},1000); 
</script>

</html>
```